# How to find a condition for coefficient of highest degree of the polynomial representing determinant of a matrix $A- I w$ to be $0$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

We know that the determinant of a matrix $A - w I$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ in $w$, that is,

$$\det(A-w I )=\sum_{i=0}^{n}c_iw^i ,$$

where $n$ is the dimension of the square matrix $A$.

My question is:

> Is there a result which would let me know when the coefficient $c_n=0$ (i.e. coefficient of $w^n$ is zero)?

If not, is there a theorem which would restrict it?

Comment: $c_n=(-1)^n{}$.

Comment: So it can never be zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $c_n=0$, then $\det(A-w I )=\sum_{i=0}^{n}c_iw^i$ is a polynomial of degree $ \le n-1$. This polynomial cannot be the characteristic polynomial of a $ n \times n $ - matrix !

As pointed out by Lord Shark the Unknown: we have $c_n=(-1)^n.$